# Magento2 select field value

Tags: magento2, select, fieldsets, field

I am having a form, and a select type field which is rendering good and have correct options but when I am editing an existing record **it won't point to the corresponding value.**

**CODE**

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'segment',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'segment',
                    'label' => __('Segment'),
                    'id' => 'segment',
                    'title' => __('Segment'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'value' => $model->getSegmentCode(),
                    'values' => $options
                ],
                'sender_email'
            );
```

What I always got is select with options.

I can't screenshot when its open :D.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the block loads values based on the data keys. Based on your sample code I am guessing the value you want is in the column `segment_code` because `$model->getSegmentCode()` is probably the same as `$model->getData('segment_code')` if you are extending `AbstractModel` or `DataObject`.

If that's the case then try changing the field name to `segment_code` and it should fill the value accordingly.